# Can I debug installed hybrid ios app from windows

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

My phonegap app is crashing randomly in some ios devices, not happening from phonegap client.

Is there a way to debug an installed ios app with a windows pc ?

Comment: I'm afraid without a virtual maschine there is no chance right now, but you can overcome this problem when you follow these [steps](http://www.macbreaker.com/2015/01/virtualbox-yosemite-zone.html). Then after installing and running yosemite you have to upgrade to el captian, otherwise you can not debug newer iOS-version apps with xcode(> iOS 9). There are also instructions for el capitan virtual maschine but these did not work with me but upgrading from yosemite to el capitan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug a Cordova app is a pain. Since the app is running inside a browser-like, all native debuggers are unuseful. In you specific case, I can suggest you to use Weinre, a remote tool able to show you something as the app is running and you can maybe catch the bug you're seeking. 
You can start reading this [link](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/) or this [link](http://www.joshmorony.com/using-weinre-to-debug-a-phonegap-build-application/) and maybe google WEINRE.

Answer (score 0):

Since your iOS app is crashing, most probably the issue will be with the Native Code.

BTW, you can try checking this tool - [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/)